# selectOneMenu style in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I have been struggling to make adjustments in the fonts size and adjustment i the selectOneMenu, but i have come to peace with it, however after upgrading PrimeFaces from 3.2 to 3.4.2, the selectOneMenu has a gap prefixed to it, which is very annoying.

**PrimeFaces 3.2 selectOneMenu**

[image: PrimeFaces 3.2 selectOneMenu]

**PrimeFaces 3.4.2 selectOneMenu**

[image: PrimeFaces 3.4.2 selectOneMenu]

**Code**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="Category" value="#{databaseSearch.category}" style=" font-size: 35px; height: 20px; width: 80px;">

                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Machine" itemValue="Machine"/>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Company" itemValue="Company"/>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Contact" itemValue="Contact"/>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Phone" itemValue="Phone"/>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Email" itemValue="Email"/>

                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

What do i do ? :(

Comment: You need overrided this **css** *.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label*

Comment: @MathewRock Would you please pass your comment as the answer ? so that i can mark it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need overrided this **css** *.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label*

Answer (score 0):

**The correct way is adding a new class and not changing default values of a framework.**

I had same problem but in my case the selectOneMenu **was used in other parts of application** therefore I could not edit that.

I made a new class in my standardStyle.css like this

```
.fullWidth {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

And then on selectOneMenu added my class as below

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="idOfSOM" value="#{mybean.value}" styleClass="fullWidth"></p:selectOneMenu>
```